# Deploying Laravel 5 to Server Issues

Tags: laravel

So I have been following a tutorial on how to do this.

1. I zipped everything but my public folder.
2. uploaded and then unzipped files in the folder before the /www folder.
3. Uploaded the .env file separately since no hidden file got uploaded.
4. put public folder into my subdomain folder. I editted the index.php appropriately to go to the right directory.

Now I am getting a blank page on the site. Into my SSH I see the files including artisan but when I do php artisan nothing happens. Even when I do php artisan tinker nothing happens.

I'm not sure what is going on... What is wrong?

Comment: Are you using apache or nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel public folder serves the content of your website. the entire framework and vendor directory are behind this path. so public users cannot access all those folders its primary security for the framework.

It means on server you don't upload the entire framework to `public_html` folder and don't point the domain to public folder of laravel without setting proper `symlink`.

This point can be done with `symlink` creation in servers. for example you can edit the host file in `Linux/Windows` and set the project domain. something like `homestead.app`. Then in your apache configuration simply set this project domain to its physical path. like below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName homestead.app
DocumentRoot /home/User/Development/homestead/public
<Directory />
Require all granted
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So you can access the project in browser like `homestead.app` for more details check this [link](http://www.walkswithme.net/laravel-setup-in-linux-machine).

Hope its clear now.

Comment: So basically, you're saying I should make a folder prior to the /www directory and place the project there, then create a symlink for the two public folders?

Comment: So I got this to work. I put the project in the public folder and switched the root of the site for /public_html/public is this a security issue?

But in SSH my php artisan is not working or activating anything!

Comment: you're working with subdomain right ? it quite simple set up the subdomain, then point the folder to public inside that. means you created a subdomain with `dev` then upload all the framework to it, in subdomain panel set the folder path to `dev/public`. Once you login with SSH simply run the commands from dev not inside public.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend putting all of your code together then creating a sym link to your public folder in your subdomain folder.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I'm not sure what a sym link is.

Comment: I can give you a concrete example in 2 hours.   You use the ln command

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the in command. I got this 
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `in'